# PowerShell: return multiple elements from ForEach-Object $_.split

Tags: split, powershell-3.0

I have a file with multiple lines, each with 5 sections deliminated by commas. I'm trying to split these lines and return multiple sections from the same line on one line. My attempt was this:

```
Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object { $_.split(",")[0,1] }
```

Unfortunately, it returns each element on a separate line. If there's another way that works within PowerShell, I'm open to that.

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object { -join $_.split(",")[0,1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is CSV, why not use Import-Csv and create an object.

```
[file.csv]
this,is,the,first,line
this,is,the,second,line
```

Then,

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\tmp\file.csv' -Header One,Two,Three,Four,Five
```

Which gives you:

```
PS> $csv | Format-Table -AutoSize

One  Two Three Four   Five
---  --- ----- ----   ----
this is  the   first  line
this is  the   second line
```

Now grab whatever you need:

```
PS> $csv[0].Four + ' ' + $csv[0].Five
first line

PS> 0..$csv.Count | % {$csv[$_].Four + ' ' + $csv[$_].Five}
first line
second line
```